# Python 'sounddevice' library error - flush invalid

Tags: python

I'm trying to run python's [sounddevice library's examples](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.3/examples.html) but they all yield the same type of error:

```
  File "spectrogram.py", line 70
    print(*line, sep='', end='\x1b[0m\n', flush=True)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and

```
File "plot_input.py", line 48
    print(status, flush=True)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I missing here? I understand that flush manages the buffers. Why do I get syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured I have to run the scripts with python3, like `'python3 plot_input.py'`

However I still get errors, python complains about numpy and mapplotlib that are already installed.